# La función await o async no esta definida

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy trabajando con **Android Studio** y **Flutter**. Al utilizar el **await** o **async** obtengo el siguiente error:

> error: The function 'await' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [asistencia] lib\main.dart:6)

Estuve investigando e hice la prueba de utilizar [async](https://pub.dev/packages/async), ya que vi que lo utilizaban en todos lados, pensé que eso solucionaría el problema pero no fue así.

El pequeño fragmento de código donde ocurre el error es el siguiente:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

var wifiBSSID = await (Connectivity().getWifiBSSID());
var wifiIP = await (Connectivity().getWifiIP());
var wifiName = await (Connectivity().getWifiName());
```

y mi archivo **pubspec.yaml** (dependencias):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  connectivity: ^0.4.8+2
  path: ^1.6.4
  async: ^2.3.1
```

Que dependencia debo de importar o que debo de realizar para poder hacer uso de **async** o **await**.

Comment: tienes que usar away dentro de un método marcado como async, no se puede declarar como variable

Comment: Yo seguí el ejemplo de conectivity: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity, entonces me podrías dar un ejemplo de como utilizarlo, podrías ponerlo como respuesta bien formateado y así podrías obtener puntuación por ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el `await` dentro de métodos, no puedes usarlo como variables, quedaría así :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

void conectar() async {

var wifiBSSID = await (Connectivity().getWifiBSSID());
var wifiIP = await (Connectivity().getWifiIP());
var wifiName = await (Connectivity().getWifiName());

}
```

Y puedes llamar al método `conectar()` dentro del `initState` por ejemplo.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    conectar();
    super.initState();
  }
```